# coordinates format to GPS

Tags: coordinate-systems, cartography

I was wondering if someone could help me figure out how to go about converting the coordinates on a map I was sent from abroad from the format I see to the usual latitude/longitude I'm used to. (I'm not a matemathician, just trying to give my parents a hand plotting this on Google Earth). What is throwing me off is I see East (este) and North (norte) on the map, but the location of this place is in Peru. Any thoughts will be much appreciated!

What I was sent is in the image.[Cartographic information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBJiA.jpg)

Comment: Is the "Distancia" column in meters? Kilometers? Miles?

Comment: The "Distancia" (I'm assuming distance between vertices) is in meters. The whole perimeter is 812.31 m.

Answer (score 2):

The last two columns are probably [UTM coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system) in meters.

South of the Equator, the "northing" coordinates are measured from an imagined line 10,000 km south of the equators, so with the values of around 8,619 km this would correspond to a latitude of about 12° S, which matches Lima.

In order to interpret the "easting" coordinates you need to know which UTM "zone" the coordinates are from, but it's probably **zone 18 South**, which roughly seems to seems to match Lima too.

This should be enough for you to type the values into an UTM converter (which I'm sure can be found somewhere on the web given a little googling, e.g. http://users.tpg.com.au/adslly6v/UtmGoogleStreetView.html).

[Also, giving the coordinates to a precision of tenths of millimeters is almost certainly overkill. For plotting on a map you can safely ignore the decimals.]

Comment: @HenningMakhlom Thank you for the hand, this makes this much clearer. I'm a little confused when using the UTM converter: When plotting a coordinate one of the vertices, I'm seeing it about 426 meters off from when I expected it to be, based on my knowledge of the land and previous maps I saw. Is there something else I need to do to the UTM converting tool other than plugging in the numbers from my two right columns and setting it to South, Zone 18 and meters?

Comment: @gonzalo2000: Such discrepancies can arise because some conversions either before or after you got the numbers use different "reference ellipsoid". Unfortunately, the exact interpretation of _both_ lat/long coordinates and UTM coordinates depend on a choice of reference ellipsoid, such that a set of coordinates interpreted in one system can point to a spot on Earth that differs by tens or hundreds of meters from the spot that the _same_ numerical coordinates refer to with another ellipsoid. And this effect works _differently_ for lat/long and UTM ...

Comment: So unless some explicit measures have been made to make sure that the same reference ellipsoid was used for _all_ of the conversions your coordinates have gone through from they were originally captured, before or after the table of values you see, _and_ the map grid you're plotting the values on (which is almost certainly not the case; most people don't even know there's a difference) such discrepancies are unfortunately to be expected. Within a small area such as this, you can trust the _relative_ differences between the positions given, though.

Answer (score 1):

What I did: Peru is close to the equator, hence angular distances are roughly proportional to horizontal distances, both north-south and east-west.
The numbers in the *Distance* column are close enough to what one computes from the *East* and *North* column differences using Pythagoras.
This suggests that the two coordinates are just measured in the same units as the distance, from some starting point.

As 8.6 million is quite large and at the same time somewhat close to the ten million meters of a meridian length (actually, that was the original definition of "meter"), I suspect that the unit is "meters" and that *North* is just the number of meters north of the South Pole (with an extraordinary sub-millimeter precision). 
That would make a *North* entry of $y\,(<10^7)$ correspond to approximately $90-\frac{9y}{1000000} $ degrees south. So I suspect that $A$ is at 12°25.38' S, approximately.

But what would then be the reference point for the *East* column? 
What interesting point or meridian is about 312 km (about  3°) west of your region of interest? Possibly the 80° W meridian?

Comment: UTM easting coordinates are measured from an imagined line 500 km west of the zone's central meridian, on an UTM-projection map, such that they are always positive. The central meridian of zone 18 is 75° W. So the actual point is 188 km west of 75° W.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah, Knowledge of the system clearly helps in decoding :)